# Python Opencv camera select timeout

Tags: python, linux, opencv, camera, python-2.7

=Question 1===========================

I'm using python 2.7.3, Ubuntu and opencv.

I used this script:

```
import sys, os
import pygtk, gtk, gobject
import pygst
import Image;
import cv;

camcapture = cv.CreateCameraCapture(0)
cv.SetCaptureProperty(camcapture,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cv.SetCaptureProperty(camcapture,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);

if not camcapture:
    print "Error opening WebCAM"
    sys.exit(1)

while 1:
frame = cv.QueryFrame(camcapture)
if frame is None:
    break
    cv.ShowImage('Camera', frame)
    k=cv.WaitKey(1);
```

And I get this:

```sh
** (test.py:21226): WARNING **: The connection is closed
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
select timeout
```

And it stops to stream the camera!
I hope you can help me!

=Question 2(additional)===========================

Do you know any Python program to find objects in a webcam image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
k=cv.WaitKey(20)
```

or

```
k=cv.WaitKey(30)
```

The program could fail because you try to access too fast to the camera.

Question2: Look at Template.

Comment: Man tha second question i found a sample in opencv docs and i will test this waitkey thank you foir the feedback

Comment: This helped the problem for me, but I still got `select timeout` errors after several seconds.